# Jetty failing when run in Maven (Saying object isn't right type when it is)

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am running into an exception when I try to start Jetty within my maven build so I can do selenium testing.

The exception that I am getting is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.0.0.RC0:run (start-jetty) on project THEPROJECTIAMWORKINGON: Failure: Object is not of type class org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext -> [Help 1]org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.0.0.RC0:run (start-jetty) on project THEPROJECTIAMWORKINGON: Failure
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:451)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failure
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:358)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:273)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:548)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:195)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object is not of type class org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:273)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.applyJettyXml(JettyRunMojo.java:540)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:289)
    ... 23 more
```

I am currently trying with just a bare bones jetty.xml to try to get it to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">


</Configure>
```

And the plugin code in the pom.xml looks like this at the moment:

> ```
>    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
>    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>    <configuration>
>      <scanIntervalSeconds>15</scanIntervalSeconds>
>      <stopKey>stop-me</stopKey>
>      <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
>    </configuration>
>    <executions>
>      <execution>
>        <id>start-jetty</id>
>        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
>        <goals>
>          <goal>run</goal>
>        </goals>
>        <configuration>
>          <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
>          <daemon>true</daemon>
>          <jettyConfig>src/test/resources/jetty.xml</jettyConfig>
>        </configuration>
>      </execution>
>      <execution>
>        <id>stop-jetty</id>
>        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
>        <goals>
>          <goal>stop</goal>
>        </goals>
>      </execution>
>    </executions>
> ```

Has anyone ever seen this before? Or have any ideas what I need to fix?

Comment: I'd start with removing any org.eclipse.* references when running from Maven, replacing them with org.mortbay.* or something similar, but I could be wrong

Comment: When I change the org.eclipse to org.mortbay it tells me that the org.mortbay class can't be found. So it seems that it is loading the org.eclipse class just fine, but it doesn't think it is the right anyways. :/

Comment: Ok, so after tinkering for a while I figured out what the problem was. I needed to have jettyEnvXml instead of jettyConfig in my POM

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, so after tinkering for a while I figured out what the problem was. I needed to have jettyEnvXml instead of jettyConfig in my POM